How to build neural network with pytorch just like xgboost
I trained and tested this dataset using XGBoost: PhiUSIIL Phishing URL (Website) and the results were excellent. However, when I built a neural network using PyTorch, I couldn’t achieve satisfactory performance. Is a neural network suitable for this type of data, and how can I construct an effective neural network?
class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ls = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(50, 25),nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(25, 2),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.ls(x)

This is my model.

Your model is probably too simple for the task. The dense architecture you're using might not work as well with this data compared to other architectures. It's useful to see how other people have approached this task using nets. This paper suggests that recurrent and convolutional architectures have worked well. Of course, you could still develop your own model further and see how it goes. I think you could start by adding more layers to it and seeing whether it results in a better score.
